# Algorithm to Cut tree and reshape?

Tags: algorithm, tree

```
      1     
    /   \    
   2     7  
  / \   / \
 3   4  5  6


    1
 / /  \ \
3 4    5 6
```

I'm looking for an algorithm to reduce a tree by cutting out nodes at a specific level and save all the leaves. This example is very simple, so the function my have to be recursive - imagine cutting a tree at level 3 and eliminating nodes at levels 4,5,6,7 - but preserving the leaves by inserting them all at level 4.

Comment: Sounds like a basic flatMap, what have you tried?

Comment: Just re-link the children of cut nodes to the cut node's parent. Of course, this will not be a binary tree anymore.

Comment: If 5, for example, has children, then what would you want the answer to be?

Comment: 1, with 4 children + 5's children - all under 1 because the user cut the tree below nodes 2 and 7.